# How to ignore touch events from presenting view controller?

Tags: ios, events, touch

After changing `UIViewController` by `performSegueWithIdentifier`, Touch Events is passed into the hidden `UIViewController` from presenting `UIViewController`.

I read about using hitTest method. But this method is useful when all views in one `UIViewController`. So, I couldn't handle this issue by this method.

Specific scenario is the following.

1. Show `FirstViewController` - touchesBegan is implemented in this controller
2. Show `SecondViewController` by `performsequeIdnetifier` from `FirstViewController`.
3. Touch the view of `SecondViewController`.
4. Touch event is detected by `FirstViewController` and do action for touching.

Why this touch events has passed through, not ignoring, the hidden `UIViewController`?

Comment: I am not sure why its behaving like this. But you perform action in firstviewcontroller touchesbegan by checking iskindofclass. If possible share code here.

Comment: I don't think it works if using 'isKindOfClass'. UIView is the same type and there is no idea how do verify the view in 'touchsbegin'.